# Cumulative array from previous rows?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a query that would push previous ids into an array, that would result in:

```
id  c_array
-----------------
1  {}
2  {1}
3  {1,2}
4  {1,2,3}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use the `array_agg` aggregate as a window function.

```
SELECT
  id,
  array_agg(id) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS c_array
FROM the_table
```

Comment: To get required results, you will need to add different frame specification:  `order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding`.

Comment: @TomasGreif Good catch. It's not inclusive of the current row, wheras the default frame specification is.

Answer (score 1):

Try Like This

```
select id, array(select l.id from table1 l where l.id< i.id order by id) as 
c_Arr from table1 i
```